# Data not updating in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

Let me start by explaining my use case, I have a fee_map attr on data which is a list of objects which contain data about the fee student has to pay, balance, payment mode etc, and a computed property, lets say 'updateOptions' which returns a list of objects with id and text suitable to populate select2(payment mode), now whenever user does something, updateOptions will be called. and on some other user actions Program will choose the selected option and set it on fee_map, structure for fee_map is as below.

```
data: {
    fee_map: {
        1: {
            details:{
                1: {
                    option_selected: "1",
                }
            }
            // other_attr
        },
        2: {
            details:{
                1: {
                    option_selected: "2",
                }
            }
            // other_attr
        },
    }
```

I have a method UpdateSelected, which will update the selections, where I loop through the fee_map by fetching keys and looping with forEach. and then set the selected option as below

```
var fee_map = this.fee_map;
t_keys = Object.keys(fee_map);
t_keys.forEach(function(t){
    f_keys = Object.keys(fee_map[t].details);
    f_keys.forEach(function(f){
         fee_map[t].details[f].option_selected = "2";
    });
});
```

Now, when I update the option_selected from here, my fee_map is not updated with new value. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your object of objects is one level deeper than you were iterating over. So when you have fee_map[t].details[f], f is the key "details"and details["details"] is undefined. You need to do a foreach for the details object as well as can be seen here.

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/78427/

```
var fee_map = this.fee_map;
  t_keys = Object.keys(fee_map);
  t_keys.forEach(function(t){
    f_keys = Object.keys(fee_map[t]);
    f_keys.forEach(function(f){
      d_keys = Object.keys(fee_map[t][f]);
      d_keys.forEach(function(d){
         fee_map[t].details[d].option_selected = "5";
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hello mthomp, sorry for the confusion, I am actually getting keys for details, which I corrected just now. I have like 10 different attributes on details like fee_amount, balance etc. I am able to update each of them within the same function but not the selected_option. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Wierd thing is that, It works fine when try the update from console, It doesnt work in that function.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was able to update the selected option using the function above. I console fee_map in the fiddle and the value changed to "5" as I set it to. Please can you be a bit clearer about the issue that's happening now

Comment: hello mthomp, found out what's going wrong with my code. I was trying to update vue data too quickly in a loop, but somehow vue is detecting changes only on the next tick, so I had to call a self invoking function as a wrapper to Vue.nextTick to preserve the context and update the selected_option inside the Vue.nextTick callback and that is working perfect. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle I found code is updating data too quickly in a loop, but somehow vue is detecting changes only on the next tick, so I had to call a self invoking function as a wrapper to Vue.nextTick to preserve the context and update the selected_option inside the Vue.nextTick callback and that is working perfect.

working code below

```
(function(fee, ref){
    console.log("Registering vue tick");
    Vue.nextTick(function(){
       console.log("Vue ticked, updating selected option");
       fee.option_selected = ref;
    });
})(fee, ref);
```